# Angular Unit Tests: "is not a function" when using provide useValue

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have the following code that mocks data from a service:

```
providers: [
        { provide: AdminService, useValue: { avcData: { runMode: 'NORMAL' } } }
      ]
```

The problem is that when I mock data with useValue, it seems like the test fails to initialize the service methods, and I get the following error in my unit test:

```
TypeError: _this.adminService.toLocalDate is not a function
```

although the method exists.

My test is simply this:

```
it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Is there any way to fix the unit test without rewriting/duplicating the method code?

Comment: *although the method exists* - it doesn't, you've just mocked the service and didn't provide toLocalDate method.

Comment: @estus I need to rewrite/duplicate the methods in my unit test as well?

Comment: If tested method uses them, than yes, they should be jasmine spies.

Comment: @estus Can you give an example? Currently I'm just trying to test that the component was created, the method is called on init. I couldn't understand frmo your comment if I have to duplicate the method or not.

Comment: `useValue: { toLocalDate: jasmine.createSpy('toLocalDate'), ... }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the 'useValue' option, you create a new signature for the object. In your code, AdminService is an object of the following structure:

```
   { avcData: { runMode: 'NORMAL' } }
```

Since this does not have a `toLocalDate` method (or any other method used in your  code), it will give the error.

If you want to utilize the methods that are present in the actual `AdminService` class, then you can use `useClass: AdminService` instead of `useValue: {}`. In that case, you will need to use spy object on functions that you need to stub.